# Pandas: Grouping a dataset Along Columns and Rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks sort of like:

```
ID| Hungry? | Height  |Outcome | other1 | other2 | other3
1    yes     tall      good
2    no      short     bad 
3    yes     medium     okay 
4    yes     tall       bad  
5    no     tall      good
5    no     short      good
5    no     short      good
```

I want to be able to arbitrarily produce two very similar outputs that aggregate the counts of each outcome divided according to the categorical or yes/no traits:

For categorical columns:

```
       |short|medium|tall|All
bad       1    0     1     2
okay      0    1     0     1
good      2    0     1     3
```

For yes/no columns:

```
      |hungry|nothungry|All
bad       1     1         2
okay      1     0         1
good      1     3         4
```

This is the same as doing df.values_count('Outcome'), but divided additionally along columns. I have tried doing this with pivot_table, but I can't figure out how to make it come out correct when I'm doing a row count rather than aggregating a pre-existing quantitative value. It ends up using all of the columns from the original dataset.

The closest I have come is

```
df.pivot_table(index='Outcome',columns='Height',aggfunc='count',values='Other1',margins=True)
```

In that case, Other1 is an arbitrary column, which seems like a kludge. Also this works correctly for my categorical columns, like Height, but I'm not sure how I can extend it to the yes/no ones.

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pandas.crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
result = pd.crosstab(index=df.Outcome,columns=df.Height, margins=True)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
Height   medium  short  tall  All
Outcome                          
bad           0      1     1    2
good          0      2     2    4
okay          1      0     0    1
All           1      3     3    7
```

The same applies for the `Hungry` column:

```
result = pd.crosstab(index=df.Outcome,columns=df.Hungry, margins=True)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
Hungry   no  yes  All
Outcome              
bad       1    1    2
good      3    1    4
okay      0    1    1
All       4    3    7
```